# Procedure to update column values in Oracle

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

With a procedure in Oracle I want to update the code field of all records in a table from an input parameter. For example, if the parameter value is 100:

row 1 with code 256 change to 101
row 2 with code 368 change to 102
row 3 with code 624 change to 103

I try this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procedure_name (parameter_newcode code%TYPE) AS
 CURSOR cursor_name IS select code from table
                           order by code asc;
  var_newCode code%TYPE;
  BEGIN
  OPEN cursor_name;
  LOOP
  FETCH cursor_name INTO var_newCode;
  EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND;
  var_newCode:=parameter_newcode+1;
  update table set code = var_newCode;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_name;
 END procedure_name;
```

but returns the same code for each row (for example, if the parameter is 100 - > 101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each loop you are setting (again and again)
`var_newCode:=parameter_newcode+1;`
and you are not specifying, which record to update
`update table set code = var_newCode;`

Something along

```
create or replace PROCEDURE procedure_name (parameter_newcode code%TYPE) AS
 CURSOR cursor_name IS select code from myTable
                           order by code asc;
  var_oldCode code%TYPE;
  var_newCode code%TYPE;
  BEGIN
  var_newCode:=parameter_newcode;
  OPEN cursor_name;
  LOOP
  FETCH cursor_name INTO var_oldCode;
  EXIT WHEN cursor_name%NOTFOUND;
  var_newCode:=var_newCode+1;
  update myTable set code = var_newCode where code = var_oldCode;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_name;
 END procedure_name;
```

should work. (Sorry can't test right now.)